# mysql not inserting info

Tags: php

The script below that I wrote won't insert field entry into the database or echo out the insert code. no errors are being shown the print_r($data) displays the csv entries in the files fine. it just won't insert or tell me why it wont

```
     $handle = fopen($uploadcsv, 'r');
   $column_headers = array();
         $row_count = 0;
     $batchid = '0000';
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($row_count==0){
                $column_headers = $data;
        } else {        

                if(file_exists('/home/domain/public_html/temp/files/'. $data[0] .'.doc')) {  
                    echo "running";             
                    $importword="INSERT into load_test(word, type, category, language, batch_id) 
                    values('$data[2]', '$data[3]', 'Class', '$data[4]', '$batchid')"; 
                    mysql_query($importword); //or die(mysql_error());

                    echo mysql_error();

                    $word_id = mysql_insert_id($importword);

                    $importwav="INSERT into names(com_id,rec_date,rec_time,rec_type,rec_request,rec_by,batch_id) 
                        values('$importword', '.date(d-M-y).', '.date('h:i:s a').', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]', '$data[4]', '$batchid')";

                    mysql_query($importwav); //or die(mysql_error());
                    echo mysql_error();
                        if(!is_dir("/home/domain/public_html/audio_rec/" . date(Y) . "/" . date(m) . "/" . $word_id)) {
                            mkdir("/home/domain/public_html/audio_rec/" . date(Y) . "/" . date(m) . "/" . $word_id, 0755, true);
                        }                       
                        rename($uploaddir . $data[0] .'.doc', $audiodir . date(Y) . '/' . date(m) . '/' . $word_id . '/' . $data[0] . '.doc');
                    }
                    print_r($data);
     }
     ++$row_count;
```

Comment: Damn why do people not [escape strings that go in SQL queries](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)? [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!! booo!!

Comment: cambraca: got any interestings links to suggest about best practices for sql security?

Comment: i escape on final code, i'm just trying to get everything to work first. this is just a test table i'm working with

Comment: @cambraca: mysql_escape_string_real is still a terrible hack; use PDO/MySQLi and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to top of script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also change your lines that are like this:

```
mysql_query(...);
```

to this:

```
$res = mysql_query(...);
echo "mysql_query result: " . var_dump($res) . "\n";
```

And report back.

Comment: no errors at all the print_r($data) is output all the csv data perfectly. so its skipping over insert sql part. i tried echoing the $word_id for the sql insert ID and nothing came back

Comment: And what does it say after "mysql_query result: " ?

Comment: nothing blank screen, and no error in the error_log either. I even misspelled the table name just to see if it would pick up on it and nothing. so thats makes me believe its not even processing the query its ending before it gets to that.

Comment: OK, so you have learned two things: 1) Add logging to your code to see what is actually being executed.  2) Your problem clearly has nothing to do at all with MySQL.

Comment: Your MySQL code isn't even executing.  Just keep adding logging until you figure out what's going on.  It's probably faulty logic in your file_exists() code or something.  Take a break, go outside, and try with fresh eyes.  :-)

Comment: you're right its halting at the File_exists() i put 
echo "../temp/files/" . $data[0] .'.wav' .  "\n"; before it and it echoed the file location but when put after the File_exists() nothing is shown. Any way I can rewrite that? i just need to make sure the file is there before processing the insert